# If you are given an unsorted list of n numbers, how long will it take to determine...

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

If you are given an unsorted list of n numbers, how long will it take to determine whether there are three numbers x, y, and z in the list such that xy = z?

Comment: It really depends on how much coffee I've had.

Comment: It depends on how you decide to approach it.  Have you thought of any algorithms to accomplish this yet?  Maybe a convenient first step is to sort the list and go from there.

Comment: Should the numbers x, y and z be distinct from each other? Our could we have the trivial solution "is 1 on the list"?

Comment: @HenriqueAugustoSouza questions like "how long does it take" are usually asking how long it takes for worst case scenario.  You may assume then that $1$ is not on the list and it would be a waste of computing power to check.

Comment: My first thought was to start with the first 2 numbers in the list, multiply them, and search the list for their product. If their product isn't on the list, then increase the index of the second number by 1 and repeat until this index equals n. If z still hasn't been found, increase the index of the first number by 1 and reset the index of the second back to one, and so on. This seems too tedious though.

Comment: @clover2004 with that algorithm, in the worst case you would have to run through all n numbers n-1 times for the first "first number", n-2 times for the second "first number" and so on. Is there a more efficient algorithm? I really don't know. But I'm guessing it should involve sorting the list using some kind of factorization, or number-theoretic property.

Comment: In any case, $\mathsf(O)(n^2 \log n)$ is an upper bound. More precisely, $c\, \Sigma_{i=1}^n i \log_2 \!i$.

Comment: @BrianO could you explain how you got that?

Comment: I was offline for a while, back. I tried to explain in a comment but I needed a bigger whiteboard so I gave an answer.

Comment: given a hash table, thats o(n), and maybe less

Comment: This maps to [3SUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM) if you can magically perform and work with perfectly accurate logarithms (or sufficiently approximate them).

Answer (score 2):

All values are assumed positive. (If not, positive and negative sublists can be handled separately.)

Sort the given list by increasing values, in time $O(n\log(n))$.

Then take a value $z$ from the array and initialize two indexes, $i_x$ and $i_y$, at the beginning and after then end of the array, corresponding to the elements $x$ and $y$. By convention, past the array $y=\infty$.

Ensure that $i_y$ is the smallest index such that $xy\ge z$ holds, by decrementing $i_y$ if necessary. If in addition $xy=z$, you are done for this $z$.

Repeatedly increment $i_x$ and decrement $i_y$ accordingly as long as $xy\ge z$. In the end, $i_x$ and $i_y$ will meet. If the condition $xy=z$ was never established, the search for this $z$ failed.

Thanks to monotonicity, the search for a $z$ takes time $O(n)$. Hence for all $z$, $O(n^2)$.

---

```
L= [3, 4, 5, 6, 21, 56, 78, 126, 280, 752]

L.append(999999)
for z in range(len(L) - 1):
    x= 0; y= len(L)
    while x < y:
        while x < y and L[x] * L[y - 1] >= L[z]:
            y-= 1
            if L[x] * L[y] == L[z]:
                print L[x], "*", L[y], "=", L[z]
        x+= 1

6 * 21 = 126
5 * 56 = 280
```

Comment: @Barry Right, you don't. I killed that comment on seeing it's true. After incrementing $i_x$, still $xy \ge z$ but the last $i_y$ is smaller, so decrement, etc.

Comment: Suppose you start with $y_1$ and $y_4$. Your algorithm won't check both $y_1y_3$ and $y_2y_4$.

Comment: Instead of `y = len(L)` you can start with `y = z`, as the elements after `z` are too big.

Comment: @BrianO Yes, other optimizations are possible like dichotomy for the initial $i_y$; I was just caring about the asymptotic complexity.

Answer (score 0):

$O(n^2 \log n)$ is an upper bound. Your question says "numbers", which I'll assume means integers (because round-off worries complicate matters, though basically the same algorithm works). Also, your question doesn't require $x$ or $y$ to be unequal to $z$, nor does it require $x \neq y$ (more precisely, doesn't require that they be at different positions in the list $a$: $i \neq j$ where $x = a[i], y = a[j]$, which is sensible in case $a$ is e.g. `(2, 4)`. 
Finally, I'll assume the list contains nonnegative integers. Generalization to signed integers is straightforward.

Here's a function which takes as parameter a list (array) `a` of nonnegative integers. If `a` contains values `x, y, z` such that `x * y = z`, the function returns a triple `(i, j, k)` such that `x == a[i], y == a]j], z == a[k]`. If `a` contains no such values, the function returns `None`.

Convention: assume indexes start at `0`, so `a = a[0:n]` where `n = length(a)` (so `a` has no element at index `n`).

Assume that there's an existing function `binsearch(arr, bottom, top, val)` which takes a sorted array `arr`, integer indexes `bottom, top`, and a value `val`. This function returns an index `j` with `bottom <= j < top` if `arr[k] == val`, otherwise it returns `-1` if `val` is not found in `a[bottom:top]`. Assume also that it implements binary search properly, so its time complexity is $O(\log_2 (top-bottom))$.

```
def find_triple(a):
    n = len(a)
    # deal with trivial cases
    if n == 0: return None
    if a[0] <= 1: return (0, 0, 0)

    # Sort a copy of a. 
    # This only costs O(n log n). Even O(n^2) is ok.
    a = sorted(a)

    for k in range(n):
        # See if there are i, j < k s.t. a[i]*a[j] == a[k]
        for i in range(k):
            # Assumption (loop invariant):
            #  for all ii < i, (a[k] // a[ii]) not in a[ii: k]
            q = a[k] // a[i]            # integer division
            if q * a[i] != a[k]:
                continue                # doesn't divide a[k] evenly; try next i
            j = binsearch(a, i, k, q)   # O(log i)
            if j != -1:                 # Found!
               return (i, j, k)
    return None
```

We sort `a` first, so that we can binary-search for quotients `a[k] // a[i]`. We can assume that `sorted` implements a sorting algorithm that's *at worst* $n^2$. Although we could assume better performance — $O(n \log n)$ by using, say, mergesort — for worst-case analysis it's unnecessary: the main loop of `find_triple` is worse than quadratic, so any not-insane sort will do. (Note: the above is valid Python, though you can just take it to be pseudocode. Python's builtin `sorted` function uses quicksort. I have a working version of `find_triple`, including a working `binsearch`.)

Given `k in range(n)`, clearly the inner loop takes `O(i log i)`. So the runtime of the main loop takes a constant factor times
$$
\begin{align}
\Sigma_{k=1}^n k \log k &\le \log n \: \Sigma_{k=1}^n k \\
&= \log n \frac {n (n+1)} 2 \\
&= O(n^2 \log n) \text{.}
\end{align}
$$
This dominates the time required to sort, so it's an upper bound for the whole function.

Comment: To see if $O(n^2\log n)$ is a lower bound as well, it might suffice to consider what happens when half your numbers have $d$ digits and the other half have $2d$ digits.  In this case you know that $x$ and $y$ have to come from the first set and $z$ from the other, but you might be able to show that you can't do better than try each pair from the first set and search for their product in the second.

Comment: @BarryCipra Hmm yes. Or, the $i^{th}$ number has $i+1$ digits — binary digits, say — and the list contains none of the products.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  If you know the $i$th number has $i+1$ digits, then you know the product of the $i$th and $j$th number has approximately $i+j+1$ digits, so you don't have much of a search to do.  It seems to me this scenario is dispatched in $O(n^2)$.

Comment: @BarryCipra You're right, such an array has too much info .